# Google Places Autocomplete - Multiple Instance Stylings

Tags: css, google-maps, google-places-api

I have two places autocomplete inputs on a page. How can I style both of the dropdown lists differently? The following works fine for styling one:

```
.pac-container{

  margin-top: -1px;
  background-color: rgb(245,245,245);
}

.pac-item *{

  font-size: 14px !important;
}

.pac-item-query{

  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Assign an id to one or both of the lists and change CSS based on id instead of class

Comment: The dropdown list doesn't appear to have a parent id associated with it. I believe google only creates one dropdown list `pac-container` per page.

Comment: Hi! Did you think any solution for this? I have the exact same problem today

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use the id of the elements to style them differently

```
#autocomplete {
  color: blue;
  background-color: black;
}
#autocomplete2 {
  color: red;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

**code snippet:**

```js
// This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
// of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

var placeSearch, autocomplete, autocomplete2;
var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initAutocomplete() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
  // location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
      types: ['geocode']
    });

  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
  // fields in the form.
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    fillInAddress(autocomplete, "");
  });

  autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete2')), {
      types: ['geocode']
    });
  autocomplete2.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    fillInAddress(autocomplete2, "2");
  });

}

function fillInAddress(autocomplete, unique) {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    if (!!document.getElementById(component + unique)) {
      document.getElementById(component + unique).value = '';
      document.getElementById(component + unique).disabled = false;
    }
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType] && document.getElementById(addressType + unique)) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType + unique).value = val;
    }
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initAutocomplete);

function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.pac-container {
  margin-top: -1px;
  background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
}
.pac-item * {
  font-size: 14px !important;
}
.pac-item-query {
  font-weight: bold;
}
#autocomplete {
  color: blue;
  background-color: black;
}
#autocomplete2 {
  color: red;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<div id="locationField">
  <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Start typing your address" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" />
</div>
<div id="addressone">
  <input type="text" id="street_number" name="street_number" />
  <input type="text" id="route" name="street_name" />
  <input type="text" id="locality" name="town_city" />
  <input type="text" id="administrative_area_level_1" name="administrative_area_level_1" />
  <input type="text" id="postal_code" name="postcode" />
  <input type="text" id="country" name="country" />
</div>
<div id="locationField2">
  <input id="autocomplete2" placeholder="Start typing your address" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" />
</div>
<div id="addresstwo">
  <input type="text" id="street_number2" name="street_number2" />
  <input type="text" id="route2" name="street_name2" />
  <input type="text" id="locality2" name="town_city2" />
  <input type="text" id="administrative_area_level_12" name="administrative_area_level_12" />
  <input type="text" id="postal_code2" name="postcode2" />
  <input type="text" id="country2" name="country2" />
</div>
```

Comment: My apologies. My original question was not specific enough. I am trying to style the dropdown lists for each autocomplete (`.pac-container`, `.pac-item`), not the actual input fields.

Comment: I would suggest you update your question then or create a new one.